# How can I calculate revenue from cost and profit margin?

Tags: percentages, percentile

Let's say I have a profit margin of 70% and expenses of $250 can I not calculate my estimated revenue?

I'm using this formula: `Profit Margin = (Revenue - Expenses) / Revenue`.

I'm trying to understand what my projected revenue would be given my profit margin and estimated cost.

I'm looking for an answer in the form of a formula for Revenue like `R = ?`.

This is probably elementary but any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\text{Profit Margin} = (\text{Revenue} - \text{Expenses}) / \text{ Revenue}.$$

We'll use $P$ for profit margin; $R$ for revenue; and $E$ for expenses.

$$\begin{align} P = \frac{R-E}R &\iff RP = R-E \text{ (provided } R \neq 0)\\ \\
&\iff RP - R = -E \\ \\ 
&\iff R(P - 1) = -E\\ \\
&\iff R = \frac E{1-P}\;\text{ (provided } P-1 \neq 0)
\end{align}$$

Now just "plug in" your values: $P = 0.7$, $E = 250$, to obtain revenue.

Comment: I think that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Right. $0.7=(R-250)/R$.  Multiply both sides by $R$ and solve for $R$.

Comment: Thanks. What would that look like as a formula: `R = ?`

Answer (score 0):

Fee Type    =   Margin-Based Fee

Total Estimated Labor Cost  USD 250,000

Margin %        50.0

---

Formula to calculate Total Estimated Revenue =  Total Cost / (1-Margin%)

250,000 / (1-0.5) = 500,000

Margin = Total Estimated Revenue - Total Estimated Labor Cost

USD 500,000 - USD   250,000 = USD   250,000

---

Total Estimated Fee/Revenue USD 500,000

Margin  USD 250,000